# Why doesn't gcc require I `#include stdio.h` in my `helloworld.c`

Tags: c, stdio

I just took a C aptitude test on http://upwork.com.

One question flummoxed me as the code contained a `printf` without a corresponding `#include stdio.h`. Essentially:

```
int main(){ 
    /* !!! some complicated logic... */

    printf("%d", blah); 
}
```

And the multiple choice contained the option of a compiler error.

So I wasn't sure if it was a trick question. But gcc compiles `int main(){ printf("foo"); }` happily on OSX.

Is this guaranteed by the standard?

Comment: Because you are using printf

Comment: @LuizMenezes That's not the reason.

Comment: You should have provided more information how you build. According to the standard the compiler shall emit a diagnostic for missing prototype, but not an error.

Comment: In C89 it is undefined behaviour with no diagnostic required, in C99 and later there is a diagnostic required.  In all cases a compiler might decide to compile it anyway and work as intended, but you can't rely on that.